# Subset sum with negative numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

So I have a given set C of n positive integers (c_1, ..., c_n). The task is to find two subsets A and B of C, where A contains only positive numbers and B contains only the negatives of the numbers in C. The sum of the two subsets A and B should then sum up to a number d (d is always positive). I need to find out whether there are two such subsets and if so, which numbers do they contain.

`For example: {3, 5, 6, 13, 24} // d = 12
 => solution: true: {5, 13} {-6}`

I know this is a variation of the subset sum problem and I've seen some solutions for a similar problem (subset sum with negative numbers) but I need to solve the problem using dynamic programming. Most solutions I've seen work with recursion, not with DP.

I think I need a 3D boolean table S(i,j,k) with size (n * n * d). But when is S(i,j,k) true and when false? Because I'd always need to check all the possible ways to compute a sum using k number where they can be both positive and negative (example: for 4 numbers {1,2,3,4} there are 2^4 ways to arrange them: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 1 - 2 + 3 + 4, 1 - 2 - 3 + 4, ..., -1 + 2 - 3 - 4, 1 - 2 - 3 - 4)

Is my thinking correct or am I already doing something wrong?

Comment: This will be a fun question, but keep in mind we are geared for programming questions, so try to come up with some code and post that as a starting point for the answerers.

Comment: What happens when d is negative? How do you define your table then?

Comment: @AspiringMat d is always positive (forgot to mention that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the standard dynamic programming subset sum algorithm on a set consisting of (c_1,c_2,...,c_n,-c_1,-c_2,...,-c_n).

This will find a subset that sums to d (or prove that none exists).

Set A to all the positive numbers in the subset, and B to all the negative numbers.

You may also wish to remove any numbers that appears in both A and B (e.g. if you have a 3 in A and -3 in B then you can remove both without changing the sum).

Comment: The problem with this is that if you want to check the boolean in a place with a negative number (for example (-c_i, d-4), you would check (-c_i-1, d-4) or (-c_i-1, d-4 + c_i). But the problem here is, that d-4 + c_i might not be part of the table. Then you would need to check if it's possible to arrange the numbers so they sum up to d-4. Which takes a lot of time... Correct me if my concerns are wrong ;)

Comment: It is indeed true that this method will need to allow you to extend the DP for values above d.  The complexity will be O(n.m) where m is the sum of all elements in C.  Are there any constraints in the problem that may tell if this is acceptable or not?  For example, the individual elements in C may be bounded, or the total sum may be constrained?

Comment: I think it's possible if we just extend the DP table to the size ((2n) x (d+c_max)) where c_max is the hightest number of the numbers in C. The table would then have c_1, ..., c_n, -c_1, ..., -c_n on one axis and 0, 1, ..., d, ..., d+c_max on the other. Then it's possible to determine all the entries by using subsetSum DP-algorithm.